# Laravel 5: User follow another user (like twitter) - how to setup relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have user table .
**Relation:** 
One user can follow more than one user. 
How to setup data structure and how to declare relationship in laravel 5.2

Output:

1. show who are my followers
2. show my following list ( I follow another user )

Answer (score 0):

1. create a table `followers` with these columns: id, user_id, follower_id

2.Create Model like

**User Model**

```
    public function following(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Follower Model**

```
    public function following(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
    }
```